# How to convert data from txt files to CSV files using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a text file [It is just a small example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHEVs.png), but the real one is pretty similar.

and I want to know how to convert the TXT file to ["CSV File" like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZEAD.png) using Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the text file contents into a list called lines.

```
text_file_path = r'some file path'

lines = []
with open(text_file_path, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

You now have a list with each line in it as a string.

Create another list with the numbers for the rows.

```
rows = range(1, len(lines))
```

Now combine them as a pandas dataframe with the desired column headings and save it to csv.

```
import pandas as pd

csv_path = r'csv file path'

df = pd.DataFrame([rows, lines], columns = ['sr. no.', 'client'])
df.to_csv(csv_path, index=False)
```